# Fetch while data using mysqli

Tags: php, for-loop, mysqli, while-loop

Hi I am a beginner in PHP.

I have a Mysql table this

```
County          | CCode
--------------- | ------
USA             | USD
Euro            | EUR
United Kingdom  | UK
Australia       | AUD
Japan           | JPY
Canada          | CAD
```

I want the result like this format, using PHP code

```
<table border =  1 width = "1200px"  style="background-color:#FFCE4B;">
<tr>
    <th class = "font-heading-currency">County</th>
    <th class = "font-heading-currency">CCode</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class = "ctryname">USA</span>
        <span class = "ctryname">Euro</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="back">USD</span>
        <span class="front">EUR</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class = "ctryname">United Kingdom</span>
        <span class = "ctryname">Australia</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="back">UK</span>
        <span class="front">AUD</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class = "ctryname">Japan</span>
        <span class = "ctryname">Canada</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="back">JPY</span>
        <span class="front">CAD</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Can any one help to write a code for this?. 
i don't have any idea about this.

Comment: Instead of asking **How?** mention your problem. Where you are getting errors and which part of your code is not working?

Comment: I can see `while` loop in your code. I can also see wrong html printing inside while

Comment: Why you are printing two times? you don't need `if` condition, just close the `table` outside the `while` loop

Comment: Please format your code properly. It helps

Comment: i have update the code. some one plz help me for this]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has not provided any attempt to code the solution.  SO is not a free coding service.  If code were cars, we repair cars -- not build cars.

Comment: @Micmackusa Thanks for your comment. if you know the answer then write a comment other wise don't write a unnecessary comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you expecting answer like this below.

```
    <?php
        $query ="SELECT * From array_test" ;
                        //echo $query;

                        $resultset = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'], $query);

                        if( !$resultset ){

                            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($GLOBALS['con']));

                        }   

                        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($resultset);
                        $var1 = array();
                        $var2 = array();

                        while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($resultset)){
                            $var1[] = $result["Country"];
                            $var2[] = $result["ccode"];
                        }
                echo '<table border =  1 width = "1200px"  style="background-color:#FFCE4B;">
        <tr>
            <th class = "font-heading-currency">County</th>
            <th class = "font-heading-currency">CCode</th>
        </tr>';
            $i= $rowcount/2;
            $j=0;
            while($i>0)
            {
            echo '<tr>
            <td>
                <span class = "ctryname">'.$var1[$j].'</span>
                <span class = "ctryname">'.$var1[$j+1].'</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="back">'.$var2[$j].'</span>
                <span class="front">'.$var2[$j+1].'</span>
            </td>
        </tr>';
            $j= $j+2;
            $i--;
            }
            echo "</table>";
?>
```